# iOS UIImageView tap only registering on top part of view

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

I am working on a project in which a Tic Tac Toe grid is being drawn on the screen.

The issue is that, for the bottom row of "tiles", the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not working properly. For the top two rows of the grid, when any part of the `UIImageView` that the recognizer is assigned to is tapped, the proper function gets called. However, for the bottom row, it only works when the very top of the `UIImageView` is tapped.

Here is the code:

```
func drawTiles() {
    for view in subviews {
        if (view as? UIImageView != nil) {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    // Upper Left Tile [0][0]
    var view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[0][0].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(upperLeftTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Upper Middle Tile [0][1]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[0][1].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(upperCenterTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + frame.width / 3, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Upper Right Tile [0][2]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[0][2].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(upperRightTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + ((frame.width / 3) * 2), y: frame.minY, width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)



    // Middle Left Tile [1][0]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[1][0].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(middleLeftTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3)), width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Middle Center Tile [1][1]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[1][1].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(middleCenterTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + ((frame.width / 3)), y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3)), width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Middle Center Tile [1][2]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[1][2].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(middleRightTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + ((frame.width / 3) * 2), y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3)), width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // FIXME: Only clicking the top of the next 3 views works

    // Lower Left Tile [2][0]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][0].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerLeftTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3) * 2), width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Lower Center Tile [2][1]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][1].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerCenterTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + ((frame.width / 3)), y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3) * 2), width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Lower Right Tile [2][2]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][2].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerRightTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + ((frame.width / 3) * 2), y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3) * 2), width: frame.width / 3, height:frame.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)
}

func upperLeftTapped() {
    tapped(row: 0, column: 0)
}

func upperCenterTapped(){
    tapped(row: 0, column: 1)
}

func upperRightTapped() {
    tapped(row: 0, column: 2)
}

func middleLeftTapped() {
    tapped(row: 1, column: 0)
}

func middleCenterTapped() {
    tapped(row: 1, column: 1)
}
func middleRightTapped() {
    tapped(row: 1, column: 2)
}

func lowerLeftTapped() {
    tapped(row: 2, column: 0)
}

func lowerCenterTapped() {
    tapped(row: 2, column: 1)
}

func lowerRightTapped() {
    tapped(row: 2, column: 2)
}

func tapped(row: Int, column: Int) {
    if (battleGround.tiles[row][column] == .empty) {
        battleGround.tiles[row][column] = currentPlayer

        drawTiles()
    }
}
```

Here is the code to pay attention to (what draws the lower row of the grid)

```
// Lower Left Tile [2][0]
view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][0].image)
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerLeftTapped)))
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3) * 2), width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
addSubview(view)

// Lower Center Tile [2][1]
view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][1].image)
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerCenterTapped)))
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + ((frame.width / 3)), y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3) * 2), width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 3)
addSubview(view)

// Lower Right Tile [2][2]
view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][2].image)
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerRightTapped)))
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + ((frame.width / 3) * 2), y: frame.minY + ((frame.height / 3) * 2), width: frame.width / 3, height:frame.height / 3)
addSubview(view)
```

**EDIT**: Here are some screenshots of the app running to give a better idea of what the issue is.

[image: image1]

This screenshot shows what an empty grid looks like.

[image: image2]

This screenshot shows the grid after I clicked on the top middle and middle left tiles of the grid. As you can see, the image is properly added.

However, if I tap on the bottom row of the grid, nothing happens. Look at this GIF:

[image: gif1]

I tapped on the bottom middle multiple times, and nothing happened. Yet tapping in the center worked properly.

Here is the interesting part: tapping on the top of that same bottom middle tile causes the image to appear. Take a look:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nailer's `clipToBounds` method helped me find the solution, but did not reveal it outright. After a couple of weeks of deliberation, it turns out that replacing most of the `frame.` with `bounds.` fixes the issue. Here is the new code.

```
func drawTiles() {
    for view in subviews {
        if (view as? UIImageView != nil) {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    // Upper Left Tile [0][0]
    var view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[0][0].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(upperLeftTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.width / 3, height: bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Upper Middle Tile [0][1]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[0][1].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(upperCenterTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + bounds.width / 3, y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.width / 3, height: bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Upper Right Tile [0][2]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[0][2].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(upperRightTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + ((bounds.width / 3) * 2), y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.width / 3, height: bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)



    // Middle Left Tile [1][0]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[1][0].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(middleLeftTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY + ((bounds.height / 3)), width: bounds.width / 3, height: bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Middle Center Tile [1][1]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[1][1].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(middleCenterTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + ((bounds.width / 3)), y: bounds.minY + ((bounds.height / 3)), width: bounds.width / 3, height: bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Middle Center Tile [1][2]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[1][2].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(middleRightTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + ((bounds.width / 3) * 2), y: bounds.minY + ((bounds.height / 3)), width: bounds.width / 3, height: bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // FIXME: Only clicking the top of the next 3 views works

    // Lower Left Tile [2][0]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][0].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerLeftTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY + ((bounds.height / 3) * 2), width: bounds.width / 3, height: bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Lower Center Tile [2][1]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][1].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerCenterTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + ((bounds.width / 3)), y: bounds.minY + ((bounds.height / 3) * 2), width: bounds.width / 3, height: bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)

    // Lower Right Tile [2][2]
    view = UIImageView(image: battleGround.tiles[2][2].image)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(lowerRightTapped)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + ((bounds.width / 3) * 2), y: bounds.minY + ((bounds.height / 3) * 2), width: bounds.width / 3, height:bounds.height / 3)
    addSubview(view)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy, and check that the view you're inserting all these tiles into actually stretches as far as you assume it's doing.

An easy test is also to use `self.clipsToBounds = YES;`
If you can't see all your tiles, your containing view isn't big enough, which means gestures won't be properly forwarded to the gesture recognizers.

Comment: Using `clipToBounds = true` shows the cutoff point, just as you said. Any idea how I would go about fixing the issue?

Comment: Ideally, you would use autolayout to lay out your views using NSLayoutConstraint. However, it might be easier for you to calculate the frame of the superview, and set the frame explicitly.

Comment: Using interface builder, you could also make this layout directly there, instead of programatically building the interface. Either way, you'll learn a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Your view can overlapped by other view. Nailer is right, just use View debugging for this problem, there you can see which view is overlap your view and fix it.